# Checking if a 2x2-matrix is linear combination of other

Tags: linear-algebra

To check whether a matrix is linear combination of others, we introduce coeffiencts as
a(X1)+b(X2)+c(X3)=X4
but **how do we deal if matrices are 2x2**?
like:
To check whether a matrix is linear combination of others, we introduce coeffiencts as
$aX_1+bX_2+cX_3=X_4
$ but **how do we deal if matrices are 2x2**?
like:

$$
a\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 7 \\
5 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
+ b \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 
2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
+ c\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: To check linear dependence of $2\times 2$ matrices, it will be useful to treat these like vectors of length four.  More rigorously, use the standard basis of $2\times 2$ matrices, $\mathbf e_{ij}$ which has entry $1$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column , zero entries elsewhere, to express everything.  You get a system of linear equations to solve.

Answer (score 4):

The left hand side becomes

$$\begin{bmatrix}
5a+b+3c&7a+2b+4c\\
5a+2b+5c&a+3b+6c
\end{bmatrix}$$

Equating this to the right hand side, you will get a system of 4 linear equations in three variables.